# Laravel not throwing an error but redirecting to login

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel project I'm encountering the following behavior which I can't isolate and what is pretty annoying e.g. when I'm sending a request to a controller and either the route or the controller does not exist, Laravel is neither logging the error nor showing the error and but always redirecting to the login page - I've searched around a lot and i may misconfigured something in the project, but can't find out what's the issue.

My Laravel Version: 7.3.4
System: Windows
Server: Wamp with Apache 2.4.39, Mysql 5.7.26, Php Version: 7.3.5

route/web

```
// Route url
Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@dashboard');
//.. custom routes
Auth::routes();
```

The Controller looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }


  // Dashboard - Ruwido
  public function dashboard(){
    $pageConfigs = [
      'pageHeader' => false
    ];

    return view('/pages/dashboard', [
      'pageConfigs' => $pageConfigs
    ]);
  }

}
```

The Error Handler

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Throwable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Has anybody ever had such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the middleware auth in the constructor which will redirect to login if the user is not authenticated and will not let the request proceed in the dashboard method. If the user is authenticated that check your default guard, maybe its pointing to api authentication and now that you are using api auth it will not authenticate via session but using api tokens; first try commenting out the middleware in the constructor;

Comment: Hi Rinor, i commented out   public function __construct()
  {
    //$this->middleware('auth');
  }
but still the same effect - i definitly know that in other projects i had an error message when there was a route missing or something like that - now nothing in the log

Comment: Route::get('/', function() {  dd("I'm here");  });  I think this is the only way to check since we don't have more information; can you try moving out of the controller and creating a closure instead

Comment: Hi Rinor, thank you for you comment, i'll try to isolate the error the way you mentioned - the thing is i might miss something which is causing this problem and it may be that due to changes things just went south ... without noticing ... thank you again!